# Button with multiple clicks that call multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have an image slider with previous and next buttons. 
How can I add another function to the next button to slide more on the second click?

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var speed = 600;
    $('#navNext').click(function () {
        $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'-665px'}, speed);
    });

    $('#navPrev').click(function () {
        $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'1px'}, speed);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="navNext" href="#" onclick="click(); return false"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a variable to keep track of how many times the button has been clicked, resetting it whenever the other button is clicked, and using that count to decide how fast to animate.

```
var nextClickCount = 0;
$('#navNext').click(function() {
    nextClickCount += 1;
    previousClickCount = 0;
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'-665px'}, nextClickCount * speed);
});
var previousClickCount = 0; //...
```